# Regrex to check decimal number in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me in giving a regex to check  below format in JavaScript

Format: 16 digit number up to three decimal points.

I am using this

```
if (/^\d+(\.\d)?\d*$/.test(str))
```

But how to check 3 decimal points after `.` and up to 16 digits only

Comment: Could you just split on the "." and check if the length of the 2nd element is 2 (3 digits)?

Comment: Can you clarify your question - part says "up to three decimal points" while another part says "check 3 decimal points" - so answers are being provided for one or the other.

Comment: upto 3 decimal point means after . max 3 numbers allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the length. If you want to restrict the length to 3 after decimal, try `/^\d+(.\d){3}$/`.

```js
var str = '1234.567';
console.log(/^\d+(.\d{3})$/.test(str));
var str1 = '1234.56';
console.log(/^\d+(.\d{3})$/.test(str1));
var str2 = '1234.5678';
console.log(/^\d+(.\d{3})$/.test(str2))
```

*Please Note:* If you want to restrict the total length to 16 (13 before and 3 after), try `/^\d{13}(.\d{3})$/`.

Comment: Allows multiple `.`, eg passes with '1234.5.6.7'

Comment: not workign, I want the regrex to allow numbers without decimal. if decimal is there then max 3 digits after decimal. if decimal is not there it should also allow

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may help, set a range

```
/^\d{1,16}(.\d{1,3})$/.test(str)
```

Comment: no, for `1234567890123456.123` your regex will pass it, while here total numbers are 19 and OP mentioned only 16 max, and that can have 3 decimal places then it will be 13+3 = 16, hope its clear?

Comment: @DeepakSharma you have a point, but specifics are debatable unless OP can clarify:  13+3=17 because it's 13+1+3 (max 16 *digits* includes `.`)

Comment: @freedomn-m I conclude that if there are few numbers after decimal, then we need to reduce the length of numbers before decimal as he said `But how to check 3 decimal points after . *and up to 16 digits only*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
var str = '1344.511';
console.log(/^\d{1,16}(.\d{1,3})$/.test(str))
var str1 = '12454.5645';
console.log(/^\d{1,16}(.\d{1,3})$/.test(str1))
var str2 = '122112222222234.567';
console.log(/^\d{1,16}(.\d{1,3})$/.test(str2))
var str3 = '122112222222234.5676';
console.log(/^\d{1,16}(.\d{1,3})$/.test(str3))
var str4 = '12211244222222234.567';
console.log(/^\d{1,16}(.\d{1,3})$/.test(str4))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```